# I make it ten pounds forty-three you owe me

Tags: grammar

> I make it ten pounds forty-three ***you owe me***. Let's call it ten pounds.

(Reference: dictionary example)
[Reference](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/call_1?q=Call)

---

I'm having trouble understanding the grammatical construction of ***you owe me***.

Is "ten pounds forty-three ***you owe me***" the same as "ten pounds forty-three which ***you owe me***"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You analysis is correct.  "you owe me" is a relative clause, in which the word "which" or "that" is not needed because the subject "you" is present in the clause.  Compare:

> This is the book (that) you gave me.

The word that or which is optional and can be omitted.